# Update expo-cli to latest version ( 3.21.3 ) failed

Tags: expo

I'm trying to update my expo cli to latest version but it gave an error like this
[image: The erros]

how to fix this ? I'm doing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running this:

npm cache clean --force

after that, try installing again